# having a PHP script echo onto the parent page

Tags: php, image, parent, echo

i'm fairly new to PHP and can't seem to figure this one out.

i've normally been able to find what i need through google and through trial and error and then figure out why it does what it does but this one is stumping me.

currently i have my php script query a thumbnail folder on my server, this in turn auto populates the page with the thumbnails. when you click on the thumbnail the you are taken to a new blank white page with the image in the top left.

my question is this, is there a way to place a target=_parent action into my script to have the larger image either open in the same page or in a new fit to size window making it easier for my eventual viewers to navigate the images.

the following is my script that i am currently using.

```
    <?php

                    $images = glob('*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

                    foreach ($images as $image) {
                        if (file_exists("./thumbs/{$image}")){
                            echo "<a href=\"{$image}\"><img src=\"thumbs/{$image}\" alt=\"{$image}\" /></a>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<a href=\"{$image}\"><img src=\"?img/{$image}\" alt=\"{$image}\" /></a>"; 
                        }
                    }

                    ?>
```

any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use JavaScript to display the image in a popup on click.

Comment: If you're trying to create an image gallery, don't reinvent the wheel. There are tons of JS-based image galleries that look incredibly professional and will do a much better job than opening pop-ops for images. For example, [check out lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Comment: thanksguys, looks like i'll be fooling around with lightbox and prettyphoto to see which one i like better then implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont think you need a php script to do it. after loading the thumbnails you can use javascript to open a lightbox to view the images.

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

check this, it is a free lightbox plugin.

Comment: i think that will work beautifully, i guess there's no time like the present to learn javascript. Just to clarify, i should still be using the first portion of the php that would auto populate the thumbnails and then have the javascript open them in the lightbox, or does the lightbox function do this as part of the script?

Comment: This is what I was thinking, I was going to suggest [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#single_image_overview) which is similar.  You just add the scripts to your page, and add `rel="prettyPhoto"` to each `<img>` tag you want to lightbox.  The one @ShivamShah recommended looks perfectly fine as well.  And the learning curve for JS on both of these is low.

Comment: thanks guys...i ended up going with lightbox for now. everything worked beautifully. just had to modify my php coding a bit so that it still automatically add's the thumbnails but now it loads the lightbox instead of a new page.